# Difference between tiffsep composite file and tiff32nc

Tags: ghostscript, cmyk

I have a PDF with spot colors and need to convert to cmyk tif. When i use the tiff32nc device i get a black and white file but if i run tiffsep i get all the separates and the composite cmyk tif is correctly colored. I suspect it has something to do with the way that overprinting is set in the PDF. Does anyone know which of the many command line parameters are executed in process of creating the composite cmyk tiff vs the tiff32nc tiff?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet so users can take a look or replicate the issue?

Comment: You haven't supplied an example file, nor a command line, nor stated which version of Ghostscript. I **very** much doubt that your problem is anything to do with overprint, but without seeing teh file its not going to be possible to make any suggestions. The two devices are quite different, its nothign to do with command line parameters, the actual code between teh devices is different, as is the colour model.

Comment: Can't provide the input but the separates are: 48253, 90342, 57377, 58600, PANTONE 471 U, PANTONE 430 U and PANTONE 300 U. I'm using basic comand lines: gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffsep -r254 -sOutputFile=output.tif Input.pdf    and   gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -r254 -sOutputFile=output.tif Input.pdf.   I'm trying to determine how to get the same results with tiif32nc as i get with the composite CMYK file created using tiffsep.  I've tried several command line paramaters and can't get it to work.